# How to fix MySQL high CPU usage running on VPS

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I manage a WordPress site on virtual private server with 2 vCore, 80GB SSD, 4GB of memory, Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4.29, and mysql community version 8.0.20.

When started the site on the server, everything worked OK, but right after running database maintenance (simple table optimization), I’m noticing high processor utilization up to 100% of the total capacity for several second, and then goes down, and the goes up again, and it’s constantly like that. After restarting the server, the high CPU usage continues.

Using the `htop` command, I can see that the problem is always a mysql process.

I tried going to mysql, and I used the  “Show processlist” command everything looks normal, and no query is hanging. If I run the command again, some WordPress related queries will be there, but redoing the command again, the queries complete successfully.

However, running queries like saving, publishing post, querying a list of posts, deleting posts the trash takes a very long time. We’re talking 10 to 20 seconds, and the homepage now takes a long time too.

I use a cache plugin and CDN, you for people the site is OK, but something isn’t right.

I tried disabling all the plugins and theme, but the CPU continues to spike up and down.

During the testing period, I turned on the “Optimize Database after Deleting Revisions” which I used for years. Trying to delete 46 pingback links 17 minutes, and the query completed successfully.

The biggest thing to note here is that before the site was running on Ubuntu 16.04 and similar hardware specs with an older version of mysql and apache, and the processor never broke a sweat (never high CPU).

During the time I spent researching, I was thinking that high processor usage was a database problem, but now, I’m thinking that it could be a mysql configuration issue.

For instance, inside `/etc/mysql` folder, there are two folders and four files, including `conf.d` and `mysql.conf.d` folders and `Debian.cnf`, `my.cnf.fallback`, `mysql.cnf` files, and there’s a `my.conf` file but it’s a symlink pointing to `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` which then points to `/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf`.

```
Inside the conf.d/mysql.cnf file, the content appears as followed:
# The MySQL  Client configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysql]
```

Inside the mysql.cnf, this is the content:

```
# The MySQL  Server configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Finally, inside the mysql.conf.d the only thing I see a mysqld.cnf file with text:

```
#
# The MySQL  Server configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysqld]
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
log-error   = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

**IMPORTANT: The below content is from the old server, not new server with the problem. I'm mentioning it below to make a point that the new server doesn't have a configure, and I'm wondering if I can use the below config to fix the issue.**

After seeing these configurations, I decided to look into one of the old backups to see the mysql configuration file, and I saw this:

In the content below, I omitted some comments to make this post a little shorter.

```
# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
```

These are my questions now:

1. The high CPU usage with mysql is because the new serve doesn't any configuration like the old server?
2. Did I check the mysql setting correctly? (I couldn't the `/etc/my.cnf`.)
3. If the problem is configuration, can the old `mysqld.cnf` be use in the new server? I mean would be compatible with new server running Ubuntu 18.04 and mysql 8?
4. Can someone provide other suggestion and/or solution to this mysql problem?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I created a dropbox folder with the information requested. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/190cw2lpfh86utg/AADfHlM54VSjAvfdZggIqITLa?dl=0

Comment: I also shared an image with the CPU usage now, and how it used too look before.

Comment: Welcome to dba.stackexchange.com  Your analysis is in process.  I will try to post suggestions within 24 hours. What is your UTC zone?  We are in UTC -6 hrs.  Please view our profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: Thank you. I'm in Eastern Time Zone. I want to emphasise that I never experience the high CPU usage. When I created the new server, I created a copy of it, then in the original server, I tried to run optimize table command in mysql, and then CPU started acting up like now. I destroyed that server, and created another one from the backup, I didn't do any table optimization, and everything was fine. Weeks later, I tried running optimization using a plugin, and since high CPU usage when running the command manually.

Comment: Could you, from your browser enter  myip.ms  and enter your domain name to see how Shared your IP address is at your VPS host?  This is a sample - 149,305 are live websites using this IP (23.2 - within the 1st 100 lines of output.  Please post the number.  Are you aware MySQL 8.0.20 has a GA date LESS THAN one month old?  Most people would not touch a new version for 6 months to avoid 'bug reporting/waiting' on the community to assist.  Would you consider Skype TALK?  Did you use an automated plugin?  Where did you get it from?  MySQLTuner is NOT an automatic tuner, only make recommendations.

Comment: The IP is dedicated to the site, no other site is using it. The update to MySQL 8.0.20 last week, but I'm having the problem for more than 2 weeks. I'm using a prebuilt VPS (DigitalOcean WordPress droplet) that originally came with Ub 18.04, MySQL 8.0.19, and Apache 2.4.29. I don't understand " within the 1st 100 lines of output. Please post the number."

Comment: A line with  
n are live websites using this IP (23.2 .....  your report would include  - 1 are live websites using this IP when checking on your domain with myip.ms   Great, you are on a dedicated DO WP Droplet.  I will prepare my suggestions in next couple of hours. Thank you.

Comment: When can we use Skype Talk to review the htop2 screen shot?  I will be available most of this afternoon.  Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com

Comment: @mhweb Did you find the Problem & Resolve?? I'm also facing a related issue. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 Digital Ocean Droplet. (Mysql 5.0.11, PHP 5.6 etc.) Whenever there is a MySQL query, The CPU goes 100% & MySQL Process takes High Memory usage (500M+). This cause Website is in almost offline mode. Please let me know if You find any Solution. Thanks.

Comment: @JensonMJohn Actually, I did, but not by fixing the issue. Instead, I created a new droplet using MySQL 7 (latest version of the 7 version).

Comment: @mhweb Maybe, I'll try that option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`key_buffer_size` implies MyISAM. Don't use for MyISAM unless you have an overwhelmingly good reason (and it is a near certainty that you don't in 2020).

query_cache almost always does more harm than good, which is why it has been completely removed in MySQL 8.0. Set:

```
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
```

1) High mysqld CPU usage is almost never caused by configuration. It is typically caused by bad queries and bad indexing.

Having said that - you don't seem to have any explicit setting for innodb_buffer_pool_size. This should probably be set to about 2GB on a non-dedicated server of that size. Unless your data is quite tiny. How big is your data?

2) Yes you did.

3) Mostly. Some options may be deprecated and removed. Options that are no longer understood by mysqld typically cause it to fail to start and have to be removed from the config.

4) Enable

```
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 0
```

Capture 24 hours of the log. It will be big.
Process it using mysqldumpslow or pt-query-digest.
Identify the slow queries and index them better where possible, or rewrite them into a more performant form where necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Out of curiosity, it was understood that the current server doesn't have any configuration and last block  under "In the content below, I omitted some comments to make this post a little shorter." was from the Old server, right?

Comment: The data is about 105mb.

Comment: That is a tiny amount of data. Assuming you don't expect it to grow much, `innodb_buffer_pool_size=128M` should be plenty. High CPU usage with that small an amount of data underscores what I said in point 1. It sounds like you have some rather bad queries in there.

Comment: It'll grow over time, slowly by it'll grow (10 to 20mb per year). Should I still use the same value?

Comment: Any reason why the new server doesn't have any configuration? Is this the default behavior?

Comment: You should be OK for the foreseeable future with 128MB. After a year or two you'll have to start increasing it. You will need some kind of performance monitoring in place to be able to establish when you need to increase it (and upgrade to a bigger server). Default configuration is next to no configuration. Most defaults are quite sensible. The one setting you should almost always change relative to your data size and server size is innodb_buffer_pool_size. Most other settings will be dependent on your actual workload.

Comment: I'm going to give your suggestions a try. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: If I enable the `slow_query_log` isn't this also going to log queries that are taking a lot of time because another hanging possible bad query that is making it slow, and it's not necessary a bad query?

Comment: The slow query log records how much of the time was spent waiting for locks. The idea is to record all of them (`long_query_time=0` means all queries that take longer than 0 seconds), and then put it through a log analyzer to see what your most problematic queries are so that you can try to do something about them.

Comment: You may as well set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 400M` after changing to InnoDB.  The slowlog has rather low overhead (except disk space).  Here is some more WP advice:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Comment: @GordanBobic I enabled slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/localhost-slow.log
long_query_time = 1 
log-queries-not-using-indexes for around 12 hours, and as expected I saw pretty much all WordPress related queries that are slow because of something else happening. Then I updated the code to long_query_time = 0 as suggested, but after two hours the CPU went to 100% constant and broke the site, I had to remove code, and restart to bring the site backup again.

Comment: Slow logging isn't usually CPU intensive. Did you run out of disk space or disk I/O? Either way, you should now have enough in your log to identify the slow queries and know which one you need to do something about.

Comment: @mhweb and Gordan When you are averaging 58 queries per second, the logging will be very busy.  10 seconds will log 580 queries with the described actions.  1 Minute of Logging will be enough to keep you busy for a long time, even with use of summary tools.

Comment: @GordanBobic I didn't run out of space, CPU stayed high making it impossible for people to load the site. Disabling slow query code made the site usable one more time. However, I use the long_query_time = 1, the logging  works ok.

Comment: @GordanBobic Here's the real question, why when setting up the server, everything about WordPress, themes, plugins, and everything worked well. Then when I tried to optimize the database manually or with a plugin, it'll finish successfully (after 20 mins, when it used to take 1 to 2 mins), and then the CPU usage goes crazy?

Comment: @mhweb What version of WordPress is running today? What version of WordPress was running 90 days ago?

Answer (score 0):

Consider enabling 6GB of swap space on the server, from today's 0 available.

At Linux command prompt, ulimit -n 20000 and press Enter 
to enable additional Open Files by the OS.  Currently limited to 1024 per ulimit -a report. This is dynamically applied, no restart required. Will be available with next stop/start of MySQL.

To make this persistent across OS shutdown/restart, follow this guide and use 20000 
where the example is for 500000.
https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

htop2 indicates there are many mysqld PID's occupied for multiple minutes, usually Sleeping,
Our General Log Analysis would enable determining why this pattern exists.

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 9 to reduce threads_created count (expensive operation)
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to use more of your SSD io capacity
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 97
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 1,744
```

Observations,
com_create_table in 4 days indicates 325,788 tables created RPhr of 3,284 for what purpose?
There were no dropped tables reported during the 4 days.

Select_scan RPhr of 482 indicates indexes are missing. Our FAQ page includes 
Q. How can I find JOINS or QUERIES not using indexes?
To assist with analysis and resolution.

Other opportunities exist to improve performance on your site.  When time permits, get in touch, please.

Comment: I appreciate the time for suggesting these modifications. I understand about the swap, but I won't be able to do it, because DO guarantees hardware problems doing so on SSD servers. I'll schedule a maintenance to test the rest of the settings. Do I have to apply settings in this order? Or apply one and test and the other settings in any order? Thank you again.

Comment: I don't know if you can answer this question, but why for weeks the server worked find, and then because trying to optimize the database the CPU starts acting up. Also, using your suggestions are we trying to mitigate or solve the problem?

Comment: I will be available tomorrow by Skype.

Comment: @mhweb One more change needed in my.cnf [mysqld] section.  internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=MEMORY.  For reference information refer to Question 267143 on this site.  Will be corrected in next release 8.0.21, whenever it is made available.  This is a covering workaround for 8.0.20.  CPU will be lowered and performance improved.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, but is the bug also included with version 8.0.19? I had the issue with version 8.0.19 and then updated to .20 and the issue continue. I have transferred the site to a new server and mysql is working fine now, but I know as soon as I run maintenance, the problem with return.

Comment: Upon checking, I'm noticing that pretty all my tables are using MyISAM, not InnoDB. Only some tablets from one plugin is using InnoDB.

Comment: @mhweb A new hosting company?  Not sure about 8.0.19. The last site I analyzed for you had 14 MyISAM and 4 Innodb tables with less than 400K data space used. This volume is not likely to have any performance issues.  Pick up the Utility Scripts mentioned earlier, please.